# Minimal totally separated spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let us call a space $(X,\tau)$ *totally separated (ts)* if for every two distinct points there is a clopen set containing one, but not the other. If for every topology $\sigma\subseteq\tau$ with $\sigma\neq \tau$ the space $(X,\sigma)$ no longer has this property we call $(X,\tau)$ *minimal ts*.

If $(X,\tau)$ is ts, does $\tau$ contain a topology $\sigma$ such that $(X,\sigma)$ is minimal ts?

Comment: A m0d space is the same thing as a Stone space (if some ultrafilter $U$ on the clopen algebra is not represented by a point of $X$, then the subalgebra that identifies $U$ with some point of $X$ still separates points of $X$).

Comment: Your definition of "zero-dimensional" is actually known as *totally disconnected*. Zero-dimensionality is usually defined as "has a basis consisting of clopen sets".

Comment: @EricWofsey I thought Stone spaces are compact? But maybe it turns out that every m0d space is compact...?

Comment: @AndrejBauer I thought *totally disconnected* means all connected components are singletons..

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: Every 0d space naturally injects into the Stone space of its clopen algebra, and if this map is not surjective then my first comment describes how to find a subalgebra that still separates points.

Comment: For small inductive dimension, zero-dimensionality is equivalent to "clopens form a basis" (see Wikipedia if you trust it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space). A space is totally disconnected iff its components are singletons, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected_space. This is equivalent to saying that every two points can be separated by a clopen, which is what you wrote.

Comment: @AndrejBauer The wiki article you quote about totally disconnected spaces implies these spaces are $T_1$ but not necessarily Hausdorff. My definition in the original post implies Hausdorffness.

Comment: It does not matter. There are Hausdorff spaces which match your definition ("clopens separate"), but they are not $0$-dimensional in the standard sense (i.e., small inductive dimension). Is there a standard notion of dimension for which your definitions means "$0$-dimensional"?

Comment: Your question is interesting. -- I was just trying to google a totally disconnected space that is not $T_2$, so far with no success. Might ask this on mse.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: An easy way to get a non-$T_2$ totally disconnected space is to take a totally disconnected space and double a non-isolated point.

Comment: something similar at this [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Disconnected_spaces) take the rationals and double 0. See also definition of *totally separated* there. Another non-T$_2$ but totally disconnected space is [Example 99 in *Counterexamples in Topology* Steen and Seebach](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gc3DAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA119&lpg=PA119&dq=minimal+totally+separated&source=bl&ots=AY8Lz8Waof&sig=h8Zzj8rYMXG2UH02pbLMvSJck-4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xpcyVeSREIGqggSwmoLQAg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=minimal%20totally%20separated&f=false) it is not *totally separated*

Comment: Replaced zero-dimensional by "totally separated"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note that a minimal totally separated space is the same thing as a Stone space.  Clearly Stone spaces are minimal totally separated (any coarser topology cannot even be Hausdorff); conversely suppose $X$ is totally separated and not Stone.  We may assume the topology on $X$ is generated by its clopen sets (otherwise they generate a coarser totally separated topology).  Then $X$ is canonically a dense subspace of the Stone space $S(B)$ of its clopen algebra $B$.  If $X$ is not all of $S(B)$, let $u\in S(B)\setminus X$ and $x\in X$.  Let $T$ be the quotient of $S(B)$ obtained by identifying $x$ and $u$; the composition $X\to S(B)\to T$ is then injective and induces another totally separated topology on $X$.  This new topology is strictly coarser than the original topology: there is some net $(x_i)$ in $X$ that converges to $u$ in $S(B)$, and this net (which had no limit in $X$ in the old topology) converges to $x$ in the new topology.

Thus a minimal totally separating topology contained in a given topology on $X$ is equivalent to a continuous bijection $X\to S$ from $X$ to a Stone space $S$.  If $A$ is the clopen algebra of $S$, then $A$ is naturally a subalgebra of the clopen algebra $B$ of $X$, and the map $X\to S$ is determined by the inclusion $A\to B$.  Thus the question can be recast as follows: given a totally separated space $X$ with clopen algebra $B$, is there a subalgebra $A\subseteq B$ such that the canonical map $X\to S(A)$ to the Stone space of $A$ is a bijection?

Let $D$ be any infinite discrete space; then I claim we can find a counterexample $X$ which is a dense subspace of the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta D$.  To find such an $X$, note that $|\beta D|=2^{2^{|D|}}$, which is the same as the number of subalgebras of the power set algebra $\mathcal{P}(D)$.  We can thus by transfinite induction build a subset $X\subset \beta D$ that contains $D$ and avoids bijecting onto $S(A)$ for each subalgebra $A\subseteq \mathcal{P}(D)$, identifying $\mathcal{P}(D)$ with the clopen algebra of $\beta D$.  Since $X$ contains $D$ as a dense subset, a clopen subset of $X$ is determined by its intersection with $D$, and so $\mathcal{P}(D)$ is also the clopen algebra of $X$.  By construction, then, the map $X\to S(A)$ is not a bijection for any subalgebra $A$ of the clopen algebra of $X$.

This is, of course, horribly nonconstructive.  It would be interesting to see an explicit counterexample.

Comment: Why are you allowed to make the assumption that the topology of $X$ is generated by the clopen sets?

Comment: Oh I see, you're saying you'll find an example which is not only totally disconnected (what OP called "0d") but is also zero-dimensional (clopens form a basis).

Comment: I just meant that for the purposes of the question, you might as well assume clopens form a basis, since if they don't then the topology they generate is a smaller 0d topology.

Comment: Ah, excellent. And so your last remark also shows that we do not even have to do anything with Stone spaces to find a counter-example: just take a totally disconnected space which is not $0$-dimensional.

Comment: @AndrejBauer: I don't understand your last comment.  (Also, thanks for the edit :) ).

Comment: The original version of this answer was wrong because it did not guarantee that $B$ was actually the entire clopen algebra of $X$; I have corrected it (at the cost of some generality).

Comment: I misunderstood something in the answer, and have to study it tomorrow again. Sorry for pre-maturely accepting; if I understand the argument tomorrow, I'll accept the answer

Comment: Is it true in general that if a space is totally separated, then it has a basis consisting of clopen sets? (Probably it is true, but off the top of my head I didn't see the argument.) When I understand this, I'll accept the answer

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen: It's not true in general, but I don't see how that's relevant to my answer.  I'll go ahead and add in the proof that minimal totally separated is equivalent to Stone to avoid any confusion.