# Are all minimal totally separated spaces compact?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let us call a space $(X,\tau)$ [*totally separated*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Disconnected_spaces) if for every two distinct points there is a clopen set containing one, but not the other. If for every topology $\sigma\subseteq\tau$ with $\sigma\neq \tau$ the space $(X,\sigma)$ no longer has this property we call $(X,\tau)$ *minimal totally separated*.

Clearly compact totally separated spaces are minimal totally separated because they are minimal Hausdorff, as a basic theorem of general topology asserts. Conversely, is every minimal totally separated space compact?

Comment: Dominic, in your two recent posts (Questions, including this one) you are using your own definition of the 0-dimensional space which drastically contradicts the well established classical topological terminology. You should add a triple X rating so that mathematicians under 18 will not be exposed to it. Other people could go on, they worked on your questions--I couldn't. Regards.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests this property (the one you call "zero-dimensional") already has a name: it's called "totally separated".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Disconnected_spaces

Comment: OK thanks for correcting my terminology, I promise to adhere to it from now on. Will change my posts on Monday, when I'm online again.

Comment: In the context of this question, it seems to me that "totally separated" and "zero-dimensional" are not that different. Namely, a *minimal* totally separated topology *is* zero-dimensional (it's generated by its clopen sets), so "minimal totally separated" is the same as "minimal zero-dimensional Hausdorff". Right?

Comment: @bof Indeed let $\tau$ be minimal totally separated, and $\sigma$ be the topology generated by the clopen sets of $\tau$. These sets remain clopen in $\sigma$, hence $\sigma$ is totally separated. Since $\tau$ was minimal, $\tau=\sigma$, that is $\tau$ is generated by its clopen sets, hence is zero-dimensional. (And of course, totally separated implies Hausdorff.) I am inclined to stick with *totally disconnected*. In Engelking's General Topology *hereditarily disconnected* and *totally disconnected* are used in place of wikipedia's *totally disconnected* and *totally separated*, respectively.

Comment: @bof Regarding terminology it might depend on whom you ask. I was used to the term *totally disconnected* (which I assumed was standard) till I saw earlier today that wikipedia used *totally separated*. I just checked Willard's General topology and Munkres Topology A first course(1975), they both agree with wikipedia that totally disconnected means components are points (hereditary disconnected by Engelking) and they do not mention totally separated, meaning quasi-components are points according to wikipedia, called totally disconnected by Engelking who suggests that his terminology is current

Comment: @Dominic You might have a difficult task choosing the correct terminology. I edited your post, using *totally separated* (following wikipedia, see my previous comment) though I am personally used to *totally disconnected*. I guess you pick which you like, not a big deal (you might edit your question one more time to replace totally separated with totally disconnected, it is up to you). You might also keep the term zero-dimensional (indicating its usual meaning, the clopen sets form a basis) also saying Hausdorff, since, as @ bof indicated, these conditions are equivalent when you say minimal.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the term "totally separated". I have replaced "zero-dimensional" by "totally separated" throughout the two recent posts about that subject.

Comment: It looks like this question has been answered by Eric Wofsey here http://mathoverflow.net/a/203252/22277 in a similar question posted.

Comment: @EricWofsey You should probably copy the first 1/2 of your answer to a related similar question, so that this question here gets officially answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that a minimal totally separated space is the same thing as a Stone space.  Clearly Stone spaces are minimal totally separated (any coarser topology cannot even be Hausdorff); conversely suppose $X$ is totally separated and not Stone.  We may assume the topology on $X$ is generated by its clopen sets (otherwise they generate a coarser totally separated topology).  Then $X$ is canonically a dense subspace of the Stone space $S(B)$ of its clopen algebra $B$.  If $X$ is not all of $S(B)$, let $u\in S(B)\setminus X$ and $x\in X$.  Let $T$ be the quotient of $S(B)$ obtained by identifying $x$ and $u$; the composition $X\to S(B)\to T$ is then injective and induces another totally separated topology on $X$.  This new topology is strictly coarser than the original topology: there is some net $(x_i)$ in $X$ that converges to $u$ in $S(B)$, and this net (which had no limit in $X$ in the old topology) converges to $x$ in the new topology.

Thus a minimal totally separating topology contained in a given topology on $X$ is equivalent to a continuous bijection $X\to S$ from $X$ to a Stone space $S$.  If $A$ is the clopen algebra of $S$, then $A$ is naturally a subalgebra of the clopen algebra $B$ of $X$, and the map $X\to S$ is determined by the inclusion $A\to B$.